# Headphone button control Android 5.0

Tags: android, android-mediasession

I am writing a program that catches the headphone button presses then do different things depending how long and how many times you press it. Going for api level 21. Android 5.0.
So I can catch the button press, but when start an mp3 player then it start catching the button presses. How can I prevent that? 
Second question how do you resume a paused mp3, its and other program not my program playing the mp3.

```
 audioSession = new MediaSession(getApplicationContext(), "TAG11");
    MsCallback=     new MediaSession.Callback() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMediaButtonEvent(final Intent mediaButtonIntent) {
            String intentAction = mediaButtonIntent.getAction();
            Log.i("onMediaButtonEvent", intentAction );
            if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intentAction)) {
                KeyEvent event = mediaButtonIntent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);

                if (event != null) {
                    if(toast!=null){
                        toast.cancel();
                    }
                    toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "headsetbutton press", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
            return super.onMediaButtonEvent(mediaButtonIntent);
        }


    };
    audioSession.setCallback(MsCallback);

    PlaybackState state = new PlaybackState.Builder()
            .setActions(PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE)
            .setState(PlaybackState.STATE_PLAYING, 0, 0, 0)
            .build();
    audioSession.setPlaybackState(state);
    audioSession.setFlags(MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS | MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);

    audioSession.setActive(true);
```

Comment: Probably not possible to block other programs from putting listeners on the button. You could maybe listen for new listeners, then remove them as they attach, but I don't know if thats even possible. Idk if highjacking the button is even a good idea. Might tick off your users who use it for music.

Comment: Thx for answering. The trick might be that you need to rehook it. But how do you detect it was stolen? Users can set what the button do so they set it to play music then it will play music. Its kinda like this program but want to make much more options. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kober.headset&hl=en

Comment: Is there a way to get a mutable list of listeners? Could just manipulate that directly.

Comment: Maybe the problem is when the mp3 player start paying then its MediaSession object gets the priority and that has its own callback. So should set my MediaSession object get the priority back. But dont know how.

Comment: do you really want to call `super.onMediaButtonEvent()` and return its value? the invocation probably does nothing, but it returns false while documentation says it should return true if the button event was handled

Comment: well it works till you start an mp3 playback

Comment: I had changed it to return true always. Nothing changed in button capture.

Answer (score 0):

In order to listen to media key events declare a broadcast reciever in your manifest file like so

```
<receiver android:name=".RemoteControlReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

In The `RemoteControlReceiver` class extend `BroadcastReceiver` and extract the key event and key code like so

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: ");
    if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        KeyEvent event = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
        int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();

    }
}
```

The basic button on every headset is usually the [Pause/Play](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE) button

Comment: You need to use  mAudioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(
                        mRemoteControlResponder);

Comment: Well you should have included how you hook RemoteControlResponder to get the intent. Like this  ` mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        mRemoteControlResponder = new ComponentName(getPackageName(),
                RemoteControlReceiver.class.getName());mAudioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(
                        mRemoteControlResponder);` and its only works below 5.0. Not sure even its works on 4.4 there you use  MediaSessionCompat.